# Why show does mysql show a Duplicate entry error

Tags: php, mysql

Duplicate entry '20' for key 'user_id'

```
$userid = its foreign key (20) 


$query = mysql_query("insert into qualification (q_id,course_name,institute_name,pass_year,user_id) values ('','$coursename','$institutename','$passyear','$userid')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to skip this error and add multiple record on the same userid ?

Comment: sure, revamp your database structure to remove the unique constraint.

Comment: Or consider using REPLACE INTO syntax if you need to overwrite an existing row or inserting a new one if unique key does not already exist.

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Comment: hey @MarcB why I remove unique constraint? i used it foregn key

Comment: No overwrite add another record same userid

Comment: why not i add multiple record same userid ?

Comment: Me thinks you should rework your database design based on the operations you want to do.

Comment: Just look at how your key is defined and the error should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this error, you have a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key constraint for user_id in your database. As Marc B already said. Remove the unique constraint from the user_id.

You asked Marc:

> Why remove unique constraint?

Simply because then you can't have two records with the same user_id in your table. Then you also can't use it as a key for table. You can still use an index on user_id to speed up queries for this field.